# Sort array according to certain rule

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to print my array equal to the area that repeats the most. But I will not print these repeating fields in the same label.
Like in the example:

```
<Variant>
<VariantCode>12111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantPrice>33.90</VariantPrice>
<VariantName1>Color</VariantName1>
<VariantValue1>Red</VariantValue1>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>38</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>13111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantPrice>33.90</VariantPrice>
<VariantName1>Color</VariantName1>
<VariantValue1>Blue</VariantValue1>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>39</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>14111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantPrice>33.90</VariantPrice>
<VariantName1>Color</VariantName1>
<VariantValue1>Dark</VariantValue1>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>40</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
```

Array values and fields are variable. The most important point here is to maintain up to the most repetitive recording with all the different recordings.

I can do the most as follows;

```
<Variant>
<VariantCode>12111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>38</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>12311_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>39</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>145111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantName2>Size</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>40</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>12111_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantName2>Color</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>Red</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
<Variant>
<VariantCode>12311_1</VariantCode>
<VariantQuantity>11</VariantQuantity>
<VariantName2>Color</VariantName2>
<VariantValue2>White</VariantValue2>
</Variant>
```

My using codes;

```
 $output .= "\n\t".'<Variants>';
                        $dizi = explode ("|",$v);
                        foreach( $dizi as $sayi => $ek)
                        {
                            $output .= "\n\t".'<Variant>';
                           
                            
                           
                            $output .= "\n\t".'<VariantQuantity><![CDATA['.html_entity_decode($dizi2[3], ENT_QUOTES).']]></VariantQuantity>';
                            $output .= "\n\t".'<VariantName1><![CDATA['.html_entity_decode($dizi2[0], ENT_QUOTES).']]></VariantName1>';
                            $output .= "\n\t".'<VariantValue1><![CDATA['.html_entity_decode($dizi2[1], ENT_QUOTES).']]></VariantValue1>';
                            $output .= "\n\t".'</Variant>';
                        }

                        $output .= "\n\t".'</Variants>';
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share the input data, and explain how it is related to the output result you want.

Comment: If you are going to build XML dynamically, use SimpleXMLElement or something similar instead of string concatenation a bunch of crap together.